# partial match between 2 sheets insert value in same row as match

Tags: excel, match, wildcard, vlookup, partial

One my sheet one:

Column A                                           Column B       Column c

51484EMK Twilight_Shimmer_and_Sky_Blossom           300.00
51713EMK_Sparkling_Blush_Digital_Images_a           2,025.00
51945EMK FY19_MK_Sparkling_Blush_IMW_Proo           0.00

I want to find partial match between the info in Column A with sheet 2 Column A:

Column A    Column B

51945       4980.00
51484       300.00
51713       50.00

Then take the value from Sheet 2 Column B that is next to the match and put it in Sheet 1 column C.

I have tried many formulas based on searches here but am not have any luck.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming the partial match is the numeric portion at the beginning of the values in Column A - e.g. 51484, 51713, and the length of this varies, and that it's not always followed by "EMK" - but please say if otherwise, it will be easier.

Comment: Hello BigBen! Yes, the partial match is of the 5 digits in Column A of Sheet1 and Column A of Sheet2. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You should be able to do this with INDEX, MATCH, and LEFT. I'm assuming part of your problem is that Sheet 2 has numbers whereas Sheet1, Column A is text. Try `=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(LEFT(A1,5)*1,Sheet2!A:A,0))` in Sheet1, C1.

Comment: Hello BigBen, Thank you, but that resulted in #N/A. What is the *1 doing in your equation, please? Thanks!!

Comment: The following is giving me the vaule in the first cell of Sheet2, B1 
    =INDEX(Sheet2!B:B&"",MATCH(LEFT(A1,5)*1,Sheet2!A:A,1))

Comment: `*1` is just converting the five digits to number format - otherwise they are text. And I think you want 0, not 1, as the last argument (match_type) in MATCH - see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: When I use 0 it results in #N/A. When I use 1 it results in the first row in the Sheet2, B Column. It seems like it is very close just somehow missing a piece that will result in the Sheet2, Column B value. Thanks!!

Comment: would the MID function be useful here? In Sheet2 Column A the match of the 5 digits will be in the middle of the entire cell.  Thanks!